# 任意のフォルダの中を検索し、条件に一致したファイルがあれば処理をするシェルスクリプトを書きたい

Tags: bash, shellscript

行いたい処理が2つあるのですがうまく書けずに困っています。
処理したい事は下記になります。

#### 1

- フォルダAの中にある*.rarを再帰的に検索
- 検索にヒットした*.rarファイルを全てzipファイル変換

```sh
if [ *.rarをfindする処理 ]; then
    *.rarをzipに変換する処理
fi
```

#### 2

- フォルダBの中にあるファイル名に大文字の空白があるファイルを再帰的に検索
- 検索にヒットしたファイルのファイル名の大文字の空白を削除する

```sh
if [ 空白文字をfindする処理 ]; then
　　sedで空白文字を削除処理
fi
```

何かいい書き方があれば教えていただければ幸いです。

例えば下記のようなディレクトリ構造です。

```
animals  
├── bird  
│   ├── bird_1.rar  
│   ├── bird_2.rar  
│   ├── bird_3.rar  
│   ├── bird_4.rar
│   ├── bird_5.rar
│   └── penguin
│       ├── p　enguin_1.txt
│       ├── p　enguin_2.txt
│       ├── p　enguin_3.txt
│       ├── p　enguin_4.txt
│       └── p　enguin_5.txt
├── cat
│   ├── cat_1.rar
│   ├── cat_2.rar
│   ├── cat_3.rar
│   ├── cat_4.rar
│   └── cat_5.rar
└── dog
    ├── dog_1.rar
    ├── dog_2.rar
    ├── dog_3.rar
    ├── dog_4.rar
    └── dog_5.rar
```

Answer (score 3):

仕事か授業の課題の丸投げですか? ヒントのみ。

指定したディレクトリ下のすべての `*.rar` ファイルを表示するだけ。`echo "$rar"` の部分を RAR → ZIP するシェルスクリプトを組めば 1 の課題は完成。

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$@" \
  -type f \
  -name '*.rar' \
  -exec sh -c \
    'for rar in "$@"; do echo "$rar"; done' \
    sh {} + \
;
```

同様に 2 も簡単ですね。

`find` の `-exec` 節のシングルクォート内にシェルスクリプトを記述するのが気持ち悪いとかなら、ちょっと遅いけどこんな風にも書けます。指定したディレクトリ下の名前にいわゆる全角スペース (U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE) を含むファイルの名前を列挙するだけの例。ただし、ファイル名に改行を含むものが存在する場合はうまく動きません。

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$@" \
  -type f \
  -name '*　*' \
  -print \
|while IFS= read -r name; do
  echo "$name"
done
```

Comment: 1 の課題で
`echo "$rar";`を`unrar x`を変更すると
`Extracting from パス名/hoge.rar`
`No files to extract`とエラーになってしまいます。
これはどのように回避すれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問者さんのコメントがうもれていたので、議論のようになっていたコメントたちをチャットに移動しました： http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69949/discussion-on-answer-by-fumiyas-

Comment: `echo "$rar";` (セミコロンも含む) を `unrar x` に置き換えたら構文エラーになるはずです。

やったことは正確に伝えてください。

Answer (score 0):

こんなかんじではどうでしょう
再帰的ではないですが、たぶん十分？

> 1
>   ・フォルダAの中にある*.rarを再帰的に検索
>   ・検索にヒットした*.rarファイルを全てzipファイル変換

```
#!/bin/bash

# 実行： ./rar2zip.sh [フォルダのパス]
#
# 以下のコマンドがいる
# realpath, unrar, zip, mktemp

function rar2zip {
    rar="$(realpath "$1")"
    zip="$(realpath "${2:-$(basename "$rar" .rar).zip}")"
    d=$(mktemp -d /tmp/rar2zip.XXXXXX)
    cd "$d"
    unrar x "$rar"
    zip -r "$zip" *
    mv -f $zip ${rar%/*}
    cd -
    rm -r "$d"
}

# 空白を含んだファイルを考慮に入れる場合以下のコメント外す
# SAVEIFS=$IFS
# IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

FILES=$(find ${1} -name \*.rar -print)

for rar in ${FILES[@]}
do
    rar2zip "${rar}"
done
# IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

**EDIT**: @nekketsuuu さんにコメントで指摘されている空白文字の対応

findとxargsで処理を書いていたのですが、これだとfindコマンドで見つけたファイルパスに空白が混じるとうまくいかないようです。

以下のサイトに関連する情報があります

- [find と xargs の組み合わせ 【2017-06-10 -exec {} + を追加】](http://x68000.q-e-d.net/~68user/unix/pickup?find#prgmemo-find-xargs)

ご指摘の通り `find ... -exec +` で実行するか `find ... -print0` でパスを取得するのがよさそうです。Emacsでgrep-findすると、`-print0` で出るのはそのためなんですねえ。

しかも、ファイルに空白が含まれているとファイルパスをシェルの配列に詰めるときファイルパスが空白で分割されて格納されてしまう…これは確かにfindから-execで実行したほうがよさそう…

> 2
>   ・フォルダBの中にあるファイル名に大文字の空白があるファイルを再帰的に検索
>   ・検索にヒットしたファイルのファイル名の大文字の空白を削除する

[Remove whitespaces from filenames in Linux [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347843/remove-whitespaces-from-filenames-in-linux)

```
#!/bin/bash

BLANK_FILES=$(find ${1} -type f -print | grep '[[:blank:]]')

for blank in ${BLANK_FILES[@]}
do
    #echo $blank
    mv "$blank" "${blank//[[:blank:]]}"
done
```

**EDIT**: コメントで提供してもらったものを追記

ワンライナー版

```
find . -type f -name "*[[:blank:]]*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//[[:blank:]]}"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: ファイル名から全角空白を取り除くのは`find . -type f -name "*[[:blank:]]*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1//[[:blank:]]}"' _ {} \;`でも大丈夫そうです。

Comment: `LANG=C grep '[[:blank:]]'` や `LC_ALL=C grep '[[:blank:]]'` などの場合には、`[[:blank:]]` に `U+3000` がマッチしなくなります。bash でしたら、`grep $'\u3000'` とすると環境変数に影響されません。

Comment: $1と${1}と[[:blank:]]の意味はなんでしょうか？
検索して調べても$1~9までは引数、[[]]はtestoコマンドという事は
わかりましたが今回のスクリプトで使われている$1と${1}と[[:blank:]]
の意味が全くわかりません。

Comment: シェル上での$1と${1}はどちらも１番目の引数を意味しており、中括弧で括るのはこれを見て　http://shellscript.sunone.me/variable.html#変数-var-に変数-var2-と変数-var3-の値を結合した値を設定

Comment: :blank: は POSIXで定められた正規表現です、結構どこでも使えるのでSEなら覚えとくと得です。ここ参照　http://www.kt.rim.or.jp/~kbk/regex/regex.html#CLASSNAME

Comment: `man bash`とか`man grep`でマニュアルを通読するのもオススメします。パラメータの展開とかパス名展開とかは結構便利なので知っているとお得かと。コマンドによってはたまに更新されていなくて`command --help`でないと最深のオプションが載っていないという事例があったりもするんですが、基本的なコマンドならおそらく大丈夫だと(個人的に)信じています。

Comment: 記載頂いたコードを読み解いてるのですが、今回の場合の引数$1は何を指しているのでしょうか？echo $1と入力しても何も値が返ってこないのでどこの値を取得しているのかよく分かりません。 JavascriptやPythonの引数は関数に渡す値くらい理解なのですが ShellScriptの引数は理解が難しいです。
引数を理解するのに参考になるページや参考書などありますでしょうか？
これもmanを読むのが適当でしょうか？

Comment: @hiropon さん、1番のシェルスクリプトは、一般的な状況において使用するには問題があります。たとえばパスに半角スペースが含まれる場合正しく動作しませんが、これは配列 `FILES` を作るところで `find` の `-print` による出力をそのまま使ってしまっているからです。きちんとは確認していませんが、他にも変数のクォート周りでバグがありそうです。個人的には [fumiyasu さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/39753/19110)のように `find` の `-exec` オプションを使用することをオススメします。

Comment: @bellsmarket さん、今回のシェルスクリプトは、たとえば `rar2zip.sh` という名前で保存されて、シェルの上で `./rar2zip.sh .` みたく、第一引数として「検索対象のパス」が指定されて実行されることが想定されています（シェルに直接1行ずつ打ち込むわけではありません）。このときの `$1` は、シェルスクリプトを実行するときに渡された第一引数になります。つまり今回の例だと `.` です。このあたりのことは `man bash` にも書いてあるのですが敷居が若干高いです。英語でも良ければたとえば http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html の 3.2.5 節で解説されています。

Comment: コマンドラインで`*.sh`を実行する場合は`./*.sh`だけで
実行する認識だったのですが、その後に今回の場合はパスを入力して使用するのですね。
私の認識ではそういったパスも`*.sh`の中に記載するのかなと思っていたので
目から鱗です。今回皆さまに教えて頂いたことを踏まえてコードを
読み解いてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

その後、皆さんから頂いた情報なども吟味して自分で下記のワンライナーのソースを
考えたのですが何か問題がありますでしょうか？

> 2
>   ・フォルダBの中にあるファイル名に大文字の空白があるファイルを再帰的に検索
>   ・検索にヒットしたファイルのファイル名の大文字の空白を削除する

```
find . -name "*　*" -print0| xargs -0 rename s/　/" "/
```